# How to make Eloquent Relationships for one to one relationship like this

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

My table structure is like this:

```
farmers
    id
    name
    education_id (used to capture max education)

educations (names of the education levels like BS / MS / PhD etc.)
    id
    name
```

I tried the following code with failure -

```
In farmers model (app/fermers.php) I added this code:

public function education()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Educations::class);
}
```

How do I setup the relationship?

Comment: "_with failure_" What failure? "_Educations::class_" Your model is called `Educations`? Do you `use App\Educations;` at the top of your file?

Comment: In yoru situation you have to use belongsTo instead of hasOne cause of Educatoin Farmers table education_id belongsTo Education Table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation education has many farmers, farmer belongs to education.

You should use `belongsTo()`:

```
public function education()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Educations::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line should be like,

```
 return $this->hasOne('App\yourModel');
```

For Example,

```
 return $this->hasOne('App\Educations');
```